# ng-show needs to 'double evaluate'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

## Summary

I want to use, for `ng-show`, an object property *that needs to be evaluated first*.

---

## Example

I have an array with `lanOption` (language) objects, that I'd like to show in a `select` element. Whether or not a language is shown depends on a variable `couID` (country) that also lives on the scope.

I'd like to include the logic, concerning showing or hiding a language, within the object by means of an additional property, which is then being used by `ng-show`, like so:

#### model

```
$scope.lanOptions = [
   {name: "English", ngShow: "1"},                      
   {name: "Danish",  ngShow: "$scope.couID='DK'"},
   {name: "French",  ngShow: "$scope.couID='FR' || $scope.couID='BE'"},
   {name: "Dutch",   ngShow: "$scope.couID='NL' || $scope.couID='BE'"}
]
```

(English should always be shown, Danish only if Denmark is selected, etc.)

#### view

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="o in lanOptions" ng-show="{{o.ngShow}}" value="{{o.name}}">{{o.name}}</option>
</select>
```

#### Issue

The important part here is the `ng-show` attribute -- is there a way to get this to work? And/or is there a better way that I'm missing? I've tried `filter:`, but unsuccessfully.

Thanks!

---

#### Edit

For clarification: this example is actually quite simplified to what I'm actually trying to do. In my actual problem, there are many more variable values that (might) influence the visibility of each individual option.

As an example, consider

```
{name: 'Basque', ngShow: "($scope.couID=='ES' || $scope.couID=='FR') && $scope.inclMinority==true"}
```

or

```
{name: 'German', ngShow: "$scope.couID=='DE' || 
                          $scope.couID=='AU' ||
                          ($scope.couID=='BE' && $scope.inclMinority==true)"}
```

, or more complex expressions.

This is why I did not just add a `couID` array as a property to each language object -- I'm sorry if I did not mention this explicitly before.

Comment: `$scope.couID='DK'` this is not comparison...

Comment: Do you really need to put expression in ngShow? However do not put `$scope.` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to fix the scope variable name in the model @ `ngShow: "$scope.couID='DK'"}` with `$scope.` What if you plan to change the variable name holding the scope or you port this model somewhere it will become unusable. Same is the case with the condition check on the property name `$scope.couID`,(perhaps you added it as a flexibility so that you can place filtering conditions to be evaluated against multiple variables against the scope like `couID` and for various different conditions). However even if you use interpolation in ngShow conditional expression in the binding `ngShow` will not get evaluated, (probably you might get syntax error as well).

It is also not a good idea using interpolations for ng-show since it looks for truthy expression which even the string `"false"` is (which is what it gets evaluated to if you use ng-show with interpolation on boolean values, leave at all your case where you have condition which will not work by default anyways), you will end up showing all the options always.

You should get out of ng-repeat usage to create the select, instead start using **[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).**

One way by keeping the conditions in the model you could evaluate ng-show expression while getting the item itself using **[$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)**, why to add an unwanted watch for `ng-show`?:-

Inject `$parse` in your controller inorder to parse the expression against the scope:-

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $parse) {
   //.....
   //In your method just return only necessary dropdown values
    $scope.getLanOptionsForCountry = function(){
      //Just filter it based on selected country and populate the select.
      return $scope.lanOptions.filter(function(itm){
                   return $parse(itm.ngShow)($scope); 
             });
    }
   //...
```

And your select will look just like:-

```
 <!-- Just added for the demo to select a country -->
 <select ng-model="couID" ng-options = "country.code as country.name for country in countries">
   <option value="">--Choose one--</option>
 </select>

<!-- This will be your selected, just added a placeholder option as well and an ngModel -->
 <select ng-model="language" ng-options = "lang.name for lang in getLanOptionsForCountry()">
   <option value="">--Choose one--</option>
 </select>
```

**[Plnkr - Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1NKIk?p=preview)**

Or you can even make your view model more portable by getting rid of the condition in it and place a filter for the country code for which alone those options will be displayed.

```
//Add a filter property which if present will display only for those country code else if will always display

 $scope.lanOptions = [
  {name: "English"},                      
  {name: "Danish",  filter: ["DK"]},
  {name: "French",  filter: ["FR", "BE"]},
  {name: "Dutch",   filter:["NL", "BE"]}
 ];

 $scope.getLanOptionsForCountry = function(){
    return $scope.lanOptions.filter(function(itm){
         return !itm.filter || (itm.filter.indexOf($scope.couID) + 1); 
    });
 }
```

**[Plnkr2 -  Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/d2IIGFUla7glv8NuHF4h?p=preview)**

*See polyfill and support for [Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)*

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!  

I hadn't used `$parse` before, but that seems to do what I need. Any idea on the performance hit that might be expected?

I'd like to get things a bit more portable, but the actual code is more complicated than the example I gave. In fact, a given option's visibility can depend on various variables' values which need to be combined with logical ORs and ANDs -- I suppose that rules out your second approach, correct?

Comment: For example: there might be a language like `{name: 'basque', ngShow: "($scope.couID=='ES' || $scope.couID=='FR') && $scope.inclMinority==true"}`, or more complex expressions. Important here is that, for conciseness and extensibility, a certain criterium that only applies to a single language, must not be mentioned in the ngShow attribute of all others. I hope that clarifies what I'm trying to acomplish.

Comment: I've edited your Plnkr to include the German-language example mentioned in my original question, and it can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qIUSxVjXYnSaUiPyTheY?p=preview) (Belgium is the country to check). It works great! So now the only question would be, if there is a possibility (and good reason) to rework it into your second example, which feels... cleaner?

Comment: @ElRudi I would go with the second example type. In your specfic case, you may want to have a property arrached to the supported langugae array. I.e you could make array of objects say `[...,{lang:"BE", inclMInority:true}, {lang:'DE'}...` (Just an example) but the point is that your logic will get abstracted out in the controller. But it is your choice. ALso it is a relevant point to use ng-options instead of ng-repeat, ng-repeat is really not to create select options. .

Comment: Hope that clarifies. You dont have to worry about performance as well (even if you use parse), the thing is you are doing the filter only during a select change..

Answer (score 0):

I would change your language options to

```
$scope.lanOptions = [
{name: "English", countries: ["EN"]},                      
{name: "Danish",  countries: ["DK"]},
{name: "French",  countries: ["FR","BE"]},
{name: "Dutch",   countries: ["NL","BE"]}
]
```

And the change your ng-show to a function call on the scope:

```
ng-show="showCountry(o)"
```

And on the scope :

```
$scope.showCountry = function (lanOption) {
                  return (lanOption.countries.indexOf("EN")> -1 
                  ||lanOption.countries.indexOf($scope.couID)>-1)
}
```

**edit:** actually, having considered this further you can dispense with the ng-show all together and replace your ng-repeat with a call to a function that simply *returns* the items you need:

```
$scope.getLanOptionsForCountry = function () {
    return @scope.lanOptions.filter( function( item) {
                     return item.countries.indexOf("EN")>-1 || 
                     item.countries.indexOf($scope.couID)
                      });

}
```

And then

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="o in getLanOptionsForCountry()" value="{{o.name}}">{{o.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree it's a good idea to keep the logic out of the language objects. However, is there a way to do that if the expressions get more complex? See the edit I made to the original question with Basque; and there might be even more variables of which the value influences the visibility of a given language.

Comment: Certainly - by expanding the logic contained within the `getLanOptionsForCountry()` function and referencing these additional variables. The important point is to stick to the Single Responsibility Principle - the controller has the logic to determine what should be selected, the view is simply enumerating the answers returned. Also, if the function needed to be shared across different controllers, you could also move this into a service which is injected into the controllers.